# Extract a string between patterns/delimiters in R

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

I have variable names in the form:

```
PP_Sample_12.GT
```

or

```
PP_Sample-17.GT
```

I'm trying to use string split to grep out the middle section: ie `Sample_12` or `Sample-17`.  However, when I do:

```
IDtmp <- sapply(strsplit(names(df[c(1:13)]),'_'),function(x) x[2])
IDs <- data.frame(sapply(strsplit(IDtmp,'.GT',fixed=T),function(x) x[1]))
```

I end up with `Sample` for `PP_Sample_12.GT`.

Is there another way to do this?  Maybe using a pattern/replace kind of function ? Though, not sure if this exists in R (but I think this  might work with `gsub`)

Comment: The reason you are not finding the error is because you have too many layers of abstraction. Instead of trying to do everything at once, work on the goal of turning `PP_Sample-17.GT` into what you want, **then** generalize.

Answer (score 6):

Using this input:

```
x <- c("PP_Sample_12.GT", "PP_Sample-17.GT")
```

**1) strsplit**.  Replace the first underscore with a dot and then split on dots:

```
spl <- strsplit(sub("_", ".", x), ".", fixed = TRUE)
sapply(spl, "[", 2)
```

**2) gsub**  Replace the prefix (`^[^_]*_`) and the suffix (`\\.[^.]*$"`) with the empty string:

```
gsub("^[^_]*_|\\.[^.]*$", "", x)
```

**3) gsubfn::strapplyc**  extract everything between underscore and dot.

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(x, "_(.*)\\.", simplify = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a `gsub` that will extract everything after the first `_` and before the last `.`

```
x<-c("PP_Sample-12.GT","PP_Sample-17.GT")
gsub(".*_(.*)\\..*","\\1", x, perl=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

This grabs the `2nd` element of each part of the list that was split and then simplifies it into a vector by subsetting the function `[`, using `sapply` to call this function for each element of the original list.

```
x <- c('PP_Sample_12.GT', 'PP_Sample-17.GT')
sapply(strsplit(x, '(?:_(?=\\D)|\\.GT)', perl = T), '[', 2)

[1] "Sample_12" "Sample-17"
```

Answer (score 0):

If they all start and end with the same characters and those characters aren't anywhere in the middle part of your string, the `gsub` expression is simple:

```
> x <- c("PP_Sample-12.GT","PP_Sample-17.GT")
> gsub('[(PP_)|(.GT)]','',x)
[1] "Sample-12" "Sample-17
```